# Proper way to validate password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a user registration page. I want user password to be from 4 to 16 symbols. I need to check that they have at least one uppercase letter and 1 digit. Than I am making md5 hash of this password and put it into database.
How do I validate it?
Validation in model tests if password is 32symbols length:

```
  validates :password, :length => { :minimum => 32 , 
            :message => 'Not an md5 password provided.' }
```

But how do I validate that password matches my requirements before making a hash of it and set appropriate errors for this validation?
I would like view to get user.errors[:password] containing something like 'Must have at least one digit.' and 'Must have at least one uppercase letter.'

Comment: Ideally, you'd provide the password to the model, which would hash it for you and relieve the caller of having to hash its own passwords (or the consequences of forgetting to).  But i'm not sure how you'd do that with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom validator method where you can do whatever you want:

```
validate :password_validation

def password_validation
  unless password.length > 32 && ... # other requirements
    errors.add(:password, 'Not an md5 password provided.')
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, sure, but It doesn't seem logical to create md5 inside of model validation. Logic goes to controller, validations go to model.

Comment: You can create an `after_validation` method if you want to separate the processes of validating the password and saving the hash.  To me a model's job is to be responsible for it's own data.  I don't think there's a problem with logic directly related to it's own data to be a part of the model.